# Android ListView with sticky header

Tags: android, listview

Is it possible to make fixed (sticky) header row in ListView, but I want it to behave like on this picture:

[image]

So, when it's not scrolled I want to show "big" header, but when user scrolls down enough, header should go to limit value (50% of header row height or something like that)... I tried to use this library:

https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView

But I didn't success with implementing this behaviour. It's possible to make the whole (full height) header row fixed, but not half or one part of it.

Comment: You could experiment with onscrolllistener and setting the header size based on scroll position.

Comment: I tried to use it, but I can't retreive current scroll Y position. I'm basically iOS developer and it's kinda different here in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
View c = listview.getChildAt(0);
int scrolly = -c.getTop() + listview.getFirstVisiblePosition() * c.getHeight();
```

To get the current Y offset, then play witn onScrollListener to set the size of your header. This basically gets the position of the first visible item, multiplies it by the height of 1 row item and adds the height of visible part of the first item resulting in offset in pixels from the start of your listview.

Comment: I tried to use this code, but I got NullPointerException on the second line.